# I've Ripped my DVDs (Movies/TV Shows), Now How do I Manage Them?

Tags: file-management, windows-media-center, media, windows-home-server

I've been ripping my DVDs (main movie or episodes to MP4) to my Windows Home Server for streaming to my HTPC, and now that I have a decent amount stored I need good a way to manage them. I would prefer to have an application that will monitor a specified folder/sub-folders and download Windows Media Center friendly meta-data (synopsis, genres, cover art, etc). I am not concerned with whether or not the application has a WHS add-in, as I am more likely to connect via Remote Desktop than the Console.

For reference I have been using the [My Movies Collection Management](http://www.mymovies.dk/products/collection-management.aspx) application, which really seems built more for full DVD ISO rips. It works well enough in general but requires a decent amount of fiddling to be just right, especially with multi-disk/file movies (such as LotR Ext Ed). I would rather not have to put so much work into managing my video collection. Also, I have not tried My Movies with episodic content (TV shows), but I have a feeling it will fail spectacularly in this regard.

The ideal solution will "just work" in the background, requiring very little hands on time (beyond initial setup), however, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've tried many products and nothing works just right. Interested responses here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply install media browser - it looks after all your movies and TV shows and adds data/images to them automatically providing you keep a decent file structure (eg. movies/movie name/movie.avi and tv shows/showname/season 1/e01.avi )

[image][image][image]

[download it here](http://www.mediabrowser.tv/)

Comment: Media Browser on the HTPC with [Media Center Master](http://www.mediacentermaster.com/) on the server is what I settled on in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Supplemental Tools for XBMC](http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?f=116) forum. I don't have a specific suggestion, but there are multiple apps there that sound like they'll fit your needs.

Comment: +1 for the huge resource. however, i'm finding that many of the applications listed there are either abandoned or in a state of extended hibernation. i have run across two programs that may work. i will try them later today